Batch file call lessc not returning control despite executing successfully
I have this batch file but can't get it to return control after chaining commands:
set hostingDir=%cd%
cd "%hostingDir%\MVC\wwwroot
call webpack --config webpack.config.js --stats=summary

cd "%hostingDir%\MVC\wwwroot\styles"

REM Compile LESS files
call "E:\Node\lessc" --glob --source-map --clean-css "style.less" "style.min.css"^
&& "E:\Node\lessc" --glob --source-map --clean-css "style-below.less" "style-below.min.css"
 
REM Return to base directory -- don't get to here
cd %hostingDir%

PAUSE

However, if I remove the chaining and call lessc on only either of the 2 less files, the entire script executes. So I know there is nothing wrong with the less files themselves. I deleted the compiled files and ran again to make sure they compile and they do. Even with both commands chained together.

I'd suggest, at a guess given the extensive documentation on lessc, that you try %% CALL "E:\Node\…

If you try to use && in a new line, then you must prefix it with a space. And the second line should also use CALL

@jeb thank you! please make this an answer so I can mark it as correct!

The first  line you've posted should be deleted, the second should read as CD "MVC\wwwroot, the next line should read as Call webpack.cmd --config webpack.config.js --stats=summary, then the next line as just CD styles. You should also use E:\Node\lessc.cmd too. e.g. Call "E:\Node\lessc.cmd" --glob --source-map --clean-css "style.less" "style.min.css" && Call "E:\Node\lessc.cmd" --glob --source-map --clean-css "style-below.less" "style-below.min.css". Then finally CD ..\..\...

Two problems.

If you try to use && in a new line, you must prefix it with a space, otherwise the first & will be escaped and the second command will be executed unconditionally.
Both commands should use CALL, because if lessc is a batch file, it would otherwise not return to the caller

